# Add Detached object to EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a detached object with many different properties. Some of these properties need to be "Attached" at some point, so that EF does not try to insert them into the database.

```
public partial class Load 
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual long CreatedByApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual long? ModifiedByApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifiedByApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ModifiedByApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual long? CoveredByApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoveredByApplicationUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CoveredByApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsNetworkLoad { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsExport { get; set; }

    public virtual bool CanTrackLoad { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual string BillingReferenceNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int LoadStatusId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LoadStatusId")]
    public virtual LoadStatus LoadStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Freight Freight { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LoadOrigin> LoadOrigins { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LoadDestination> LoadDestinations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LoadNote> LoadNotes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LoadCarrier> LoadCarriers { get; set; }

}
```

Take my property LoadCarries for example. LoadCarries has a property Carrier that is populated from the db with no tracking.

```
public partial class LoadCarrier
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual bool IsDispatched { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public virtual string CarrierProNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public virtual string RCNotes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int CarrierId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CarrierId")]
    public virtual Carrier Carrier { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public virtual string Dispatcher { get; set; }

    public virtual long LoadId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LoadId")]
    public virtual Load Load { get; set; }

    public virtual LoadDriver LoadDriver { get; set; }
}
```

Once I have my object populated properly, I try to save to the db. Since these object are all detached the save fails because I have a unique constraint on members of the Carriers object because EF incorrectly tries to insert an object that already exists in the db.

```
    public virtual int Create(T entity, long userId)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        dbSet.Add(entity);
        return context.SaveChanges(userId);
    }
```

I have tried several times to change the state of the Carriers object to "Unchanged", but the I get a duplicate primary key exception. I've also tried to add the Load object to the context and then set the Carrier object to an object I explicitly pull from the db. Is there a way by which I can attach this detached object properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the Carrier property of LoadCarrier, but instead only set the CarrierId.
This is enough for EF to know that it has to set the foreign key to an existing record.

There are other ways to do this, but since the Carrier is detached, it is most likely better to keep it attached and not to pull it in in the first place. I imagine you are preloading the carriers untracked because they are kind of fixed.

Comment: I tried this method as well. When I use dbSet.Add(entity) EF populates LoadCarrier from the db but it still tries to Insert into the Carrier table. The issue may be that LoadCarrier is a new object that should be inserted but its member Carrier should NOT be inserted and LoadCarrier should have a foreign key to Carrier.

Comment: As I told you you don't set the navigation properties but set the foreign key values. As such no inserts will happen.

Comment: That's what I'm saying I've tried. http://snag.gy/YO9TE.jpg. 
As you can see the Carrier object is null but the foreign key, CarrierId, is set.

Comment: Are you sure about the exception you get ? Based on the snapshot I'd say that part is correct. EF might have problems with some other relationships. Using the foreign keys are the key to your problem I think.

Comment: I have a constraint on a property in Carrier [Index("IX_MCNumber", IsUnique = true)]. So that's the exception that's being thrown. 
http://snag.gy/iM9Ie.jpg

Comment: Take a look at the queries that EF is sending over. If you use the foreignkeys you cannot have an insert in the carrier table.

Comment: You were right about the id's, which I thought all along. I had a nested object/id carrier combination that was throwing off EF. Thanks.